# Flash ActionScript 3 - Draw static 3D cube

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d, cube, perspective

I'm trying to draw a 10x10 grid with Actionscript 3 with a vanishing point behind - so each square looks like it's coming towards the screen (each from its own relative perspective).

I've found many tutorials for 3D perspective cubes, but they all revolve around movement.  Surely static shapes must be easier, but I'm yet to find any help regarding them.

Is there some way I can use [PerspectiveProjection()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/PerspectiveProjection.html) in my case where it doesn't involve movement?  It looks to be exactly what I want, yet seems reliant on movement.

Or are there any other methods for 3D perspective object creation?
I'd prefer to use internal AS3 functions if possible.
The closest I've got was this [tutorial](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/actionscript/3dwireframe.htm) , which I could likely apply to my situation, but I want to make sure there's not an easier/cleaner way before attempting it.

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. "I'd prefer to use internal AS3 functions if possible" - The entire flash platform is based on a RUNTIME, which means you don't get to write any new functions into it because it's not open sourced. Do you mean you don't want to use any AS3 libraries like away3D to do... well.. 3D?

Comment: Seriously; use Papervision3D... It's extremely simple and most tutorials will get you rendering a static cube within the first 3 minutes.

Comment: Yes, by internal functions I meant AS3 libraries.  Thanks for pointing that out so fluently.
I'll give one of those a go then, didn't want to use external libraries for how little It'll be using 3D in the project but it seems the best way. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the fastest and probably most recommended way to achieve what you're after:

- [Download the Papervision3D library for AS3](http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/downloads/list).

Once you've done this, create a document class and paste inside it this code that I've created for you to get you started:

```
package
{
    import org.papervision3d.view.BasicView;
    import org.papervision3d.objects.primitives.Cube;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.utils.MaterialsList;
    import org.papervision3d.materials.ColorMaterial;


    /**
     * Document class.
     * @author Marty Wallace.
     */
    public class Base extends BasicView
    {

        /**
         * Constructor.
         */
        public function Base()
        {

            // Create an array of faces for your cube.
            var faces:Array = [
                "front",
                "back",
                "left",
                "right",
                "top",
                "bottom"
            ];

            // Create a list of materials, which contains a material for each face of the cube.
            var list:MaterialsList = new MaterialsList();


            // Create a new material for each face.
            for each(var i:String in faces)
            {
                // Define the material.
                var material:ColorMaterial = new ColorMaterial(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF);

                // Add your material to the face represented by i.
                list.addMaterial(material, i);
            }


            // Create the Cube.
            var cube:Cube = new Cube(list, 250, 250, 250);


            // Rotate the cube to however required.
            cube.rotationX = Math.random()*360;
            cube.rotationY = Math.random()*360;
            cube.rotationZ = Math.random()*360;


            // Add the cube to the scene.
            scene.addChild(cube);


            // Render the cube.
            startRendering();

        }

    }
}
```

The majority of the code is pretty self explanatory and there are `uint.MAX_VALUE` tutorials around for this particular framework.

Enjoy!

Comment: My only concern in the loading time now - this is for a flash game.  Is the loading time spent loading the library? (ie, a one off), or will it increase relatively with the more 3D I use?  Would away3dLite be more suitable? (I hear it's practically a branch of papervision3d anyway), or Stage 3d? Unity?

Comment: @Pinch Easiest thing to do here is simply check out the SWF file size as you go. For a Flash game I would aim for under 10MB max if you're planning to distribute to Newgrounds, Kongregate, Mochimedia etc.

Comment: Simply, the library will add a "one off" chunk of data to your swf, and will not be included twice if you use the same library code twice, for example. If the library is well written, and you only use some of the code in the library, the compiler will be able to get away with including only part of the library. If you use all of the library code, this will force it to be completely included in the swf.